# Read part of a JSON String using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

The JSON string is as follows

```
{
   "rank":"-text_relevance",
   "match-expr":"(label 'star wars')",
   "hits":{
      "found":7,
      "start":0,
      "hit":[
         {"id":"tt1185834",
             "data":{
                "actor":["Abercrombie, Ian","Baker, Dee","Burton, Corey"],
                "title":["Star Wars: The Clone Wars"]
             }
         },
         .
         .
         .
         {"id":"tt0121766",
             "data":{
                "actor":["Bai, Ling","Bryant, Gene","Castle-Hughes, Keisha"],
                "title":["Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith"]
             }
         }
       ]
    },
    "info":{
       "rid":"b7c167f6c2da6d93531b9a7b314ad030b3a74803b4b7797edb905ba5a6a08",
       "time-ms":2,
       "cpu-time-ms":0
    }
    }
```

It has  many fields, but I just have want the Data field. This won't work:

```
mapper.readvalue(jsonString,Data.class);
```

How do I make Jackson read just the "Data" field?

Answer (score 34):

Jackson 2.3 now has a JsonPointer class you can use. There's a simple example in their [quick overview](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2013/11/entry_483.html) for the release.

> Usage is simple: for JSON like
>
> ```
> {
>     "address" : { "street" : "2940 5th Ave", "zip" : 980021 },   
>     "dimensions" : [ 10.0, 20.0, 15.0 ] 
> }
> ```
>
> you could use expressions like:
>
> ```
>   JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(src); 
>   int zip =root.at("/address/zip").asIntValue(); 
>   double height = root.add("/dimensions/1").asDoubleValue();// assuming it's the second number in there
> ```

Comment: What is the `mapper` object here ?  An ObjectMapper ?

Answer (score 15):

I think that the easiest way to do this is using the Jackson [TreeModel](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel): let Jackson parse the JSON input into a [`JsonNode`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.3.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.html) object that you then query, assuming some knowledge of the data structure. This way you can ignore most of the data, walking down the `JsonNodes` to the data that you want.

```
// String input = The JSON data from your question
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readValue(input.getBytes(), JsonNode.class); 

// can also use ArrayNode here, but JsonNode allows us to get(index) line an array:
JsonNode hits = rootNode.get("hits");

// can also use ObjectNodes here:
JsonNode oneHit = null;
JsonNode dataObj = null;

int idx = 0;

Data data = null;


if (hits != null)
{
    hits = hits.get("hit");

    if (hits != null)
    {
        while ((oneHit = hits.get(idx)) != null)
        {
            dataObj = oneHit.get("data");
            System.out.println("Data[" + idx + "]: " + dataObj);
            idx++;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 Data[0]: {"id":"tt1185834","data":{"actor":["Abercrombie, Ian","Baker, Dee","Burton, Corey"],"title":["Star Wars: The Clone Wars"]}}
 Data[1]: {"id":"tt0121766","data":{"actor":["Bai, Ling","Bryant, Gene","Castle-Hughes, Keisha"],"title":["Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith"]}}
```

You can still use your `Data` class implementation, but I believe this will require getting the `String` representing each `data` - as above relying on `toString`, or using `JsonNode.getText()` - and re-parsing it using the `ObjectMapper`:

```
mapper.readValue(dataArray, Data.class));
```

The alternative is to use the Jackson Streaming Model, and intercept the nodes yourself until you see the part of the input that marks the beginning of each `data` element, then consume the string and call `objectMapper.readValue` on the contents, for each string.

Answer (score 5):

Json-path could be a very good alternative for such a requirement - if you are okay with a solution other than Jackson that is: http://code.google.com/p/json-path/